# Hiding nth column

Tags: excel, vba

I want a code to hide every two columns with an interval of 1 column. Can anyone help with a VBA script. Eg. Col C&D, F&G, I&J needs to be hidden.

The range is dynamic and subject to change with increase in records.

Comment: Have you tried to record a macro ?

Comment: I was able to find some code from internet, however it is only hiding a single column. I am not able to alter it for hiding multiple columns.

Comment: Sub TotalHide()
    Dim FirstCol As Integer, LastCol As Integer
    Dim ColCount As Integer
     
    FirstCol = ActiveCell.Column
    LastCol = FindLastColumn(ActiveSheet)
    If Not LastCol > FirstCol Then Exit Sub
    If IsOdd(LastCol) And Not IsOdd(FirstCol) Then LastCol = LastCol - 1
    If Not IsOdd(LastCol) And IsOdd(FirstCol) Then LastCol = LastCol - 1
    'establish columns To work With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For ColCount = LastCol To FirstCol Step -3
        ActiveSheet.Columns(ColCount).Hidden = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True     
End Sub

Comment: Function FindLastColumn(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Integer
    With ws
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
            'Search For any entry, by searching backwards by Columns.
            FindLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        End If
    End With
End Function
 
Function IsOdd(ByVal l As Long) As Boolean
    IsOdd = l Mod 2
End Function

Comment: Please edit your question instead of writing these large comments, it makes it much more readable for everyone trying to answer. :-)

Comment: Roger that :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count Step 3
    Selection.Columns(i + 1).Hidden = True
    Selection.Columns(i + 2).Hidden = True
Next i
```

Should work with any selection.

```
Dim st As Long, sp As Long
st = Selection.Column
sp = Selection.End(xlToRight).Column
Dim i As Integer
For i = st To sp Step 3
    Cells.Columns(i + 1).Hidden = True
    Cells.Columns(i + 2).Hidden = True
Next i
```

Will hide 2 columns every 3 starting from the current cell up to the last column used in the row of the selected cell.

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty decent. I would require the "i" to function until the last column available.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked. :) i just amended a few according to my requirement and spot on.